# Configurable product multi base currency setting is not taken over when creating simple products

Tags: magento2, price, multistore, multicurrency

I have three websites and Store A (base currency Japanese YEN) and B and C  (base currencies are EURO).

I create a configurable product, imput price in Yen (e.g. 30000yen), save, then switch to B and C and input each prices in EURO (e.g. 250eur).

After that, I create simple products related to it (= size variations) and save them.

Simple products are having only 30000yen as value and when I switch stores, store B and C are having 30000eur instead of 250eur. So I manually need to change them.

Is there any fixes for this issue?

Comment: Can you create issue for this on github?

Comment: ok, I will post this.